# Swift Application not saving photos to library

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

I wrote this program that applies filters to images and then the user can save them into the library but the saving function is not working whatsoever, not even errors.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var filterName: UILabel!
    let context = CIContext()
    var original: UIImage!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        filterName.text = ""
    }
    
    @IBAction func choosePhoto(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.navigationController?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func applySepia() {
        if original == nil {
            return
        }

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
        print("Sepia")
        filterName.text = "Sepia"
        filter?.setValue(CIImage(image: original), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter?.setValue(1.0, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
        display(filter: filter!)
    }

    @IBAction func applyNoir() {
        if original == nil {
            return
        }

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")
        print("Noir")
        filterName.text = "Noir"
        filter?.setValue(CIImage(image: original), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        display(filter: filter!)
    }

    @IBAction func applyVintage() {
        if original == nil {
            return
        }
        
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectProcess")
        print("Vintage")
        filterName.text = "Vintage"
        filter?.setValue(CIImage(image: original), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        display(filter: filter!)
    }


    
    @IBAction func applySomething() {
        if original == nil {
            return
        }
        
        let number = Int.random(in: 1 ... 3)
        switch number {
        case 1:
            print("Vignette")
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIVignette")
            filterName.text = "Vignette"
            filter?.setValue(CIImage(image: original!), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter?.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
            filter?.setValue(2.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
            display(filter: filter!)
        case 2:
            print("Box Blur")
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIBoxBlur")
            filterName.text = "Box Blur"
            filter?.setValue(CIImage(image: original), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter?.setValue(30, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
            display(filter: filter!)
        case 3:
            print("Crop")
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
            filterName.text = "Crop"
            filter?.setValue(CIImage(image: original), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter?.setValue([0, 0, 300, 300], forKey: kCIAttributeTypeRectangle)
            display(filter: filter!)
        default:
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
            print("Sepia")
            filterName.text = "Sepia"
            filter?.setValue(CIImage(image: original), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter?.setValue(1.0, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
            display(filter: filter!)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func savePhoto() {
        if original == nil {
            return
        }
        
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image!, self, nil, nil)
        // add an alert when saved
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Saved Successfully", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    
    func display(filter: CIFilter) {
        let output = filter.outputImage!
        imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: self.context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)!)
    }

    func imagePickerController(
        _ picker: UIImagePickerController,
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]
    ) {
        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.image = image
            original = image
        }
    }
}
```

Also have in consideration that I added the permission in the info.plist file. Any tips? Thanks.

EDIT: I changed the savePhoto function and created a new one:

```
    @IBAction func savePhoto() {
        if original == nil {
            return
        }
        
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }
    
    @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Saved Successfully", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Saved")
        }
    }
```

Comment: There probably is an error, but you don’t see it because you’re using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum wrong. You forgot the completion function.

Comment: @matt how would you go about implementing it? I have never used the function before so any tip is helpful

Comment: I would implement it correctly. Your first `nil` should be a selector method which you should implement as shown in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum Then you will be called back with the results of the save, success or error. Remember, too, saving takes _time_. Do not do anything _after_ the call; do it only in the _callback_ method.

Comment: For an example, look at how I use `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/ce00bb7f6abd528f1d02c458eaf3428479577ff6/iOS12bookExamples/bk2ch15p660EmbeddedAVKit/EmbeddedAVKit/ViewController.swift - it's the identical syntax

Comment: hey @matt I checked out your code and changed mine, I added an edit into the question, but it still does not save, maybe the error is somewhere else? What do you think?

Comment: Cool! So now debug. Set some breakpoints. Is `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` actually being called? If not, it's because `original` is `nil`. If it is, then is any of your completion function called? If not, it has the wrong signature. (For example, perhaps your UnsafeRawPointer should be UnsafeMutableRawPointer? I'm not sure.)

Comment: I solved it @matt thanks for the help, It was a rookie mistake, I did not set it up correctly in the storyboard

Comment: Hahaha! Cool, glad you got it all sorted. (We have all been rookies and we have all made every possible rookie mistake, and from time to time we still do, so don't feel bad.)

Comment: Appreciate the help and the comment man! Good luck @matt